# Problem with passing string parameter to ControlSetText() value

Tags: c#, autoit

I'm getting an error when trying to pass a CMD parameter to `ControlSetText()` as string:

[image: error]

> Line 2  (File "C:\Temp\Automation-Testing\UploadInvoice2.exe"): Error:
> Array variable has incorrect number of subscripts or subscript
> dimension range exceeded.

AutoIt script:

```
ControlFocus("Open","","Edit1")
ControlSetText("Open","","Edit1", $CmdLine[1])
ControlClick("Open","","Button1")
```

C# project:

```
using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start($"{Path.Combine(FrameworkConfig.BrowserDownloadFilePath, uploadInvoice2.Name)} \"{Path.Combine(FrameworkConfig.BrowserDownloadFilePath, testInvoice.Name)}\""))
           {
                exeProcess.WaitForExit();
           }
```

That string in `Process.Start` returns:

```
C:\Temp\Automation-Testing\UploadInvoice2.exe "C:\Temp\Automation-Testing\TestInvoice.txt"
```

Which points to existing files in that folder:

[image: here]

So I'm putting string "C:\Temp\Automation-Testing\TestInvoice.txt" as parameter. If I hard-code that path in the AutoIt script it works:

```
ControlFocus("Open","","Edit1")
ControlSetText("Open","","Edit1","C:\Temp\Automation-Testing\TestInvoice.txt")
ControlClick("Open","","Button1")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not too familiar with AutoIT, however I think the arguments are zero-indexed, and hence should be $CmdLine[0] instead of $CmdLine[1].

Comment: Thanks for answer, i checked that to be sure, but actually $CmdLine[0] according to documentation, 0 element returns count of parameters
https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/running.htm#CommandLine

Comment: Ok. sorry for that answer. Can you check the below https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=net-5.0 . It gives the parameters for Process.Start() method. here the executable and arguments are separate parameters. However looks like in the code process.Start() is accepting a single parameter.